# Disabling Vue devtools for Vite + Vue 3 project

Tags: vue.js, vite, vue-devtools

Web-app built with
Vue.js v3.3.4
Vite v4.4.9

On my production web-site octo-buy.com you may notice that Vue-devtools are getting full access to the page. Which is totally wrong because it is a Production version and devtools should be blocked there.

Devtools are turning ON and OFF depending NODE_ENV mode and I have a feeling that Vite messes up it's modes completely.

"vite build" command executes the following script: "run-p type-check "build-only {@}" --"

No `--mode` specified and according to [Vite's docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) it will build for Production by default.

However when logging the ENV data on production web app i see

```
BASE_URL: "/"
DEV: true
MODE: "production"
PROD: false
```

And ... it doesn't make much sense to me.

Locally i see this:

```
BASE_URL: "/"
DEV: true
MODE: "development"
PROD: false
```

Here is my vite.config:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import vueJsx from "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

Also i have 2 .env files: `.env` and `.env.development` and honestly they work perfectly fine.

Initial problem is that on my PRODUCTION website the Vue.js devtools are active which is not OK security-wise. And it seems that Vue devtools are watching PROD value from ENV.

Any idea how to eventually set PROD in vite to be TRUE when it is running in PRODUCTION?

I tried adding

```
define: {
    "process.env": {
      NODE_ENV: "development",
    },
  },
```

Into vite.config to kinda FORCE it run in production - nothing helps.
I tried running `vite build --mode production` - doesn't help.
I tried setting `NODE_ENV="production"` directly in `.env` files - doesn't help.

Comment: try `define: { __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false }`.  I will say, turning it off doesn't necessarily help with "security".  It's all javascript and can be toggled on and off pretty trivially with the browser dev tools.

Comment: Will try, thanks